# How can a REST server coordinate access to a shared resource or 'critical section'?

Tags: spring-boot, rest

There is a UI which displays data in an editable table, about a large number of trading stocks.
A user can edit any of the data of a stock.
The app server is Spring Boot.
How does one handle concurrent edits to the same stock?

(I suppose if source code is an analogy, then Git allows concurrent edits but PVCS does not allow).

With a stateful server, one would store a hash map of `<Stock Id, User Id>` and have an endpoint
`wantsToEdit(Integer StockId)`. The hashmap would be a singleton.

Every time a user tries to edit a stock (puts a cursor in a UI field), then `wantsToEdit(Integer StockId)` is called and the user id added to the map (`hashmap.put(stockId,userId)`) so the server can keep track of who is editing what (and perhaps disallow concurrent edits).

But can a stateless REST server like Spring Boot store the hashmap without having an in memory database?

Comment: This is bad design. If user quits the ui then your server is always holding your user who  Is editing the stock

Comment: the user has to login and logout or is timed out and has a session id. So when the session is invalid the user id can be removed from the hashmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP 1.1 (and beyond) supports optimistic locking through the usage of [`Last-Modified`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.2) and/or [`ETag`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3) headers, as defined in [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232).

Here, the server basically sends a certain timestamp or hash-value of the content with the response that a client can use to request retrieval or update of that specific resource only in cases the server still has the same timestamp or hash-value assigned to that resource. If in the meantime some other client altered that resource, the server should return a different timestamp/hash-value for that resource and as a consequence prevent update of that resource.

As such, I'd recommend to use the optimistic locking approach as defined in RFC 7232 instead of using some arbitrary UI based locking that may lead to dead-lock situation at some point.

Comment: I agree this approach will prevent the database from being updated with data having an older timestamp . But it will not prevent the user from editing and trying to submit the field in the first place. In other words now we have the problem of deciding what to do with the data the user typed in.

Comment: @likejudo A client can change its document anytime it wants to, there is nothing wrong with it, though the important aspect is, that the "truth", the reference state, is on the server and a client that wants to make its state of the document accessible to others needs to first send its version to the server, which has to accept it and apply the changes first. Next, [HTTP is just a document management protocol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s). As such, it couldn't care less about your UI.

Comment: Is there a way in Spring to push the new timestamp for a recently updated Stock, to all the other clients? Then they can refresh the data in their browsers.

Comment: @likejudo If you are interested in a so called RESTful sollution, no. But I have the gut feeling you don't really care for all the promises REST offers but just want to get your job done and hence prefer an RPC-based solution. Here you need either a Web socket like solution or [Firebase Cloud Messaging push notifications](https://blog.mestwin.net/send-push-notifications-from-spring-boot-server-side-application-using-fcm/). Note you should avoid using the term REST for your service though

Comment: I wanted to coordinate access to the 'critical sections'. So that if a particular stock is being edited, then perhaps the UI widget is disabled for all other clients.